# Not able to give link with anchor in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, sitecore-mvc

I am working on Sitecore 7.1 version of sitecore, In rich text field i want to give link to another page(item) with anchor with it, but it seems like it is not possible through sitecore link of item.

Example: I have Item named "Prescribing Information", I want to give the link to this item from some rich text field with anchor "medication_guide" to it.

URL: www.domain.com/prescribing-information#medication_guide

Could you please suggest how I can achieve it through sitecore rich text field without any customization.

Regards
Nishant

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer, from HTML view of the rich text field we can add the anchor, example :

<- a href="~/link.aspx?_id=3D9FD5BFBDFE4B35B4521EFD579825CB&_z=z#medication_guide" ->

aftrer _z=z attribute we can add our own anchor.

Regards,
Nishant